# Replacing an element recursively with f#

Tags: recursion, f#

When I have the `value` go first and `index` come second in the argument list. The following code works

```
let rec replace value index list =
    match index, list with
    | 0, x::xs -> value::xs
    | index, x::xs -> x::replace value (index - 1) xs
    | index, [] -> failwith "index out of range"

let replaceCharArray = replace 'd' 1 ['a';'b';'c']
printfn "%A" replaceCharArray

let reversed_list = replace 100 2 [10;2;35;43;57]
printfn "%A" reversed_list
```

However, as soon as I swap `value` and `index` in the argument list my code breaks. I even have my arguments swapped so the index comes first and the replacement value comes after when I call the function, to prevent any issues, but I am still having issues.

```
let rec replace index value list =
    match index, list with
    | 0, x::xs -> value::xs
    | index, x::xs -> x::replace value (index - 1) xs
    | index, [] -> failwith "index out of range"

let replacedCharArray = replace 1 'd' ['a';'b';'c']
printfn "%A" replacedCharArray

let replacedNumList = replace 2 100 [10;2;35;43;57]
printfn "%A" replacedNumList
```

Could someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't swap the parameters where you recurse. Change line 4 to:

```
| index, x::xs -> x :: replace (index - 1) value xs
```